# How to get max length of a property using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity where I have few string properties. I have set the `MaxLength` for them in my model class. Now I want to get the max length of each field. How can I achieve it?

```
public class Customer
{
        [Key]
        public int CustId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Cust { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2)]
        public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it's not clear how you want to get the max length. can you please elaborate or give example?

Comment: You can access the information in a variety of ways but it depends on where and when you want to access to it.

Comment: I just simply want to get the length of each property from another class. @AluanHaddad

Comment: Are you trying to do this after you've created a database context instance? Are you trying to write a custom migration generator? Add some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please find the below-attached code for your reference :**

You can access the max length using `System.Reflection`.

```
 var maxLength = typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Street").GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>().Length;
    
 Console.WriteLine(maxLength);
```

Comment: I wrote the same on the (now deleted) previous answer. This is **not** the way to get that info in EF Core. In general (with concrete code example), yes. For EF Core, no. Because in EF Core the max length (and other attributes) can be specified in various ways (`[MaxLength]` attribute is just one of them), hence the information should be retrieved from EF Core entity model metadata, not with reflection. Or, if OP removes EF Core tag, then this would be a valid answer, even though it will be a duplicate of a more general question of how to obtain attribute/value for a property/field/class etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetMaxLengthAttributeForProperties<T>()
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
    var results = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    props.ForEach(p =>
    {
        var maxLength = p.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>()?.Length;
        if (maxLength != null)
            results.Add(p.Name, (int)maxLength);
    });
    return results;
}
```

Called via:

```
var results = GetMaxLengthAttributeForProperties<Customer>();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
```

Or even more generically:

```
public Dictionary<string, TPropertyValue> GetAttributeValuesForProperties<T, TPropertyValue>(Func<PropertyInfo, TPropertyValue> selector)
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
    var results = new Dictionary<string, TPropertyValue>();
    props.ForEach(p =>
    {
        var val = selector(p);
        if (val != null)
            results.Add(p.Name, (TPropertyValue)val);
    });
    return results;
}
```

called via:

```
Func<PropertyInfo, int?> selector = (i) => i.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>()?.Length;
var results = GetAttributeValuesForProperties<Customer, int?>(selector);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
```